# std::thread constructor argument error Invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, multithreading

Im writing multithreading application with thread manager contains all the threads and allows to operate them, but when im passing any arguments to constructor of std::thread, i get Error: Invalid using of non-static member function.

First thing i did was trying to pass simple void function(void), so it would be easy to do and check if it's even working. I tried passing void  ClassName::function(void) and void this->function(void), but nothing works. I even tried passing reference to function in all the way i said before, but it made even more errors in the code.

Also i don't want to change any function to static, so please try to help with this without turning functions to static.

ThreadManager.cpp:

```cpp
class ThreadMaster
{
    static thread *m_threads[MAX_THREADS_ALLOC];
...

public:

    static void addThread(thread *thrd, int *ret);
...
};

thread *ThreadMaster::m_threads[MAX_THREADS_ALLOC] = {nullptr};
mutex ThreadMaster::m_mtx;


void ThreadMaster::addThread(thread *thrd, int *ret)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS_ALLOC; i++)
    {
        if(ThreadMaster::m_threads[i] != nullptr)
        {
            ThreadMaster::m_threads[i] = thrd;

            if(ret != nullptr)
                (*ret) = i;
        }
    }
}
```

SocketManager.cpp:

```cpp
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class SocketApplication
{
...
protected:
 void check_thread(int thr, int *client );
 void thr_process(int *curcli);
...
}

void SocketApplication::check_thread(int thr, int *client)
{
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2500));
    if(threadTimer.GetTime() > 2)
    {
        ThreadMaster::joinThread(thr);
        write(m_sockmgr->GetDevice(*client)->socket, "tot", sizeof(char) * 3);
        m_sockmgr->removeClient(*client);
        printf("[-] some client is not responding\n");
        ThreadMaster::addThread(new thread(this->thr_process, client), nullptr); //error
        ThreadMaster::addThread(nullptr, nullptr); //no errors
    }
}
```

g++ compiler (g++ ./src/main.cpp -lpthread -std=c++14 -Wno-write-strings -fpermissive -o ./build/server)

```sh
./src/net/socketManager.cpp:152:69: error: invalid use of non-static member function
         ThreadMaster::addThread(new thread(this->thr_process, client), nullptr);
```

I expect this code to compile without any errors, so it can successful work, but as you can see it gives compile error.

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please. There's not enough information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new thread(this->thr_process, client)
```

That's not how to address a member function, plus you need to bind the `this` pointer so the thread knows what object to call it on.

Fortunately, `thread`'s constructor makes this easy (recall that there is a hidden "this" first argument to member functions, which this feature simulates):

```
new thread(&thr_process, this, client)
```

Read the chapter in your book about threads for more information.

Also consider reducing your excessive use of dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it worked. I spent all the day trying the most different ways of fixing this error and i haven't even thought i can do like this. Thank you.

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work! Read your book (or [a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread))

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the boost library, and this is a cut & paste of some of my code:

```
boost::thread * myThread = new boost::thread(&TCPServerMaster::run, this);
```

Here's a non-boost thread:

```
subscriptionThread = new thread(std::bind(&PubNubREST::subscriptionRunner, this));
```

The second argument in both cases is the object to run against. In my case, I have a startThread() method, the runner is against the same object.

Comment: You don’t need `std::bind`. The `std::thread` constructor knows how to do that.