# What is the meaning of passing class pointer "this" as a second parameter of emplace_back of std::vector?

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty understanding the purpose and use of class pointer **this** as second parameter in the `emplace_back` function of `std::vector`?

```
class TaskExecutor
{
    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    ...

    TaskExecutor(size_t size = 4) : stop{ false } 
    {
        size = size < 1 ? 1 : size;
        for (size_t i = 0; i< size; ++i) 
        {
            pool.emplace_back(&TaskExecutor::schedual, this);    // push_back(std::thread{...}) 
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

The above function is a class constructor, a piece of code I am studying.

Comment: `emplace_back` is being used to construct a `std::thread`, so try looking at the constructors for that class ...

Comment: `emplace_back` creates a new object by forwarding the arguments to the appropriate constructor for the vector's element type. (As the comment hints at, it's *almost* the same as `pool.push_back(std::thread(&TaskExecutor::schedual, this))`.)

Comment: `this` is the (usually implicit) first argument to the non-static member function. See also `std::invoke` and this answer [std::thread constructor argument error Invalid use of non-static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434693/stdthread-constructor-argument-error-invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function)

Comment: @Botje thanks, that explains it. Because the function **schedule** has no parameter and I was wandering why pass **this** pointer. The need to link the member function to object make a lot of sense. Do you know which constructor it is in the VC/include/thread file?

Comment: @Botje  could you add your comment as answer so this question could be closed?

Comment: It was a vote to close as duplicate, actually.

Answer (score 0):

`emplace_back` forwards the passed arguments to the constructor of the type of the `vector`.
This avoids unnecessary copies because the object is constructed directly in the vector with the supplied constructor arguments.